# Date Picker exclude days from PHP Variables

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have some boolean values stored in a MySQL database for a user's availability:

```
$available_monday = $settings['available_monday'];
$available_tuesday = $settings['available_tuesday'];
$available_wednesday = $settings['available_wednesday'];
$available_thursday = $settings['available_thursday'];
$available_friday = $settings['available_friday'];
$available_saturday = $settings['available_saturday'];
$available_sunday = $settings['available_sunday'];
```

If the value of any above is true, the user is available on that day.

I would like the available days to show on a datepicker calendar.

I know I first need to add the available dates to an array.

```
var daysAvailable = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($availableDates); ?>');
```

This is where I get confused. The code below works for a specific yy-mm-date, but I want to go by day of week instead (Monday, Tuesday, etc).

How can I alter it to block out days based on the user's availability?

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date ), daysAvailable) > -1) {
            return [false, "highlighted", "Booked out"];
        } else {
            return [true, "", "available"];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) method of the date class like this:

```
var days = [
   "Sunday",
   "Monday",
   "Tuesday",
   "Wednesday",
   "Thursday",
   "Friday",
   "Saturday"
];

$('#date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if($.inArray(days[date.getDay()], daysAvailable) > -1) {
            return [true, "", "available"];
        } else {
            return [false, "highlighted", "Booked out"];
        }
    }
});
```

This assumes that daysAvailable is in the following format:

```
var daysAvailable = [
    "Monday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Friday"
]
```